# mongoDB bulk insert blocks server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert

I have a node.js web application that uses MongoDB version 3.2.

I'm trying to upsert 160,000 small documents (containing short texts) into a collection using bulk insert.

It works fine and takes around 20 seconds to complete on my machine. The problem is, that during the 20 seconds, the web application gets almost completely blocked, so any request hangs until the insert operation is finished.

```
var bulk = this.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (var i = 0; i < ctx.models.length; i++)
{
  var model = ctx.models[i];
  bulk.find({
    guid: model.guid
  })
  .upsert()
  .updateOne(model); 
}
bulk.execute();
```

When I change the code above and use `initializeOorderedBulkOp` instead, it works a bit better but still the website is very slow.

I can not believe that MongoDB write performance is that bad. It is not a problem that the operation takes long, but blocking the whole app is not acceptable.

Is there any other approach to insert many documents in mongoDB?

Thanks

Comment: Japanese says: you can eat an elephant, but never try do it at once. Split insert into 10k chunks

Comment: I will try that. But I read in the docs that MongoDB does that already (create groups of max 1K operations): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/

Comment: yes that's serverside operation. Doing this on client side will give a breath to disk :-)